# requesting security token from STS with gSoap

Tags: security, request, token, gsoap

I'm using gSoap 2.8.17 with C++ and need to request a security token from the STS.

I added wsee to my client code by following this:

Run wsdl2h -t typemap.dat on a WSDL of a service that requires WS-Security headers. The typemap.dat file is used to recognize and translate Security header blocks for XML signature and encryption.
Run soapcpp2 on the header file produced by wsdl2h.
(Re-)compile stdsoap2.c/pp, dom.c/pp, smdevp.c, mecevp.c, wsseapi.c and the generated source files with the -DWITH_DOM and -DWITH_OPENSSL compile flags set. The smdevp.c, mecevp.c, and wsseapi.c files are located in the 'plugin' directory.

I'm not clear how to add WS-Trust to my client code though.
I generated WS-Trust.h like this
wsdl2h -g -t ....\WS\WS-typemap.dat -x wsdl1.wsdl wsdl2.wsdl

WS-Trust.h contains Request token functions but I don't see an implementation for these.
/// Top-level root element "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust":RequestSecurityToken of type "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust":RequestSecurityTokenType.
/// Note: use wsdl2h option -g to auto-generate a top-level root element declaration and processing code.

Do I add WS-Trust.h (11 MB file) to my client proxy?

What are the steps to enable a client to use WS-Trust?

Answer (score 0):

To generate the WS-Trust functions in the same header file as the other wsdls the -o argument is needed.

Example:
    wsdl2h -t typemap.dat -o myService.h -x myService1.wsdl myService2.wsdl ../../WS/WS-Trust.wsdl

After running soapcpp2 I now see the request token functions declaration and implementation.